# How to pass multiple urls from text fields into array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to enter multiple urls from text field as input, into array to extract some data.

Here's my code

```
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="urls[]" cols="150" rows="15" value=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Get URLs" />
</form>
```

---

```
if (isset($_POST['urls']) && !empty($_POST['urls'])) {
  // fetch data from specified url

    foreach($_POST['urls'] as $key => $value){ 
        $data = array($value); 
        $r = multiRequest($data);
    }
}
foreach ($r as $key => $url){

$res = preg_match_all( "/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i", 
$url, $matches);

if($res) {
    foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
        echo $email . "<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "No data found.";
}

unset($value);
```

Now if I enter single url,`www.example1.com`, if fetches the data (email). But if I enter more than one url in the form, it doesn't works (No data found).

If I define url in array manually

```
$data = array('www.example1.com', 'www.example2.com', 'www.example3.com');
```

I can extract the data (email).

How to do it for multiple entries?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `one value` in `$data array` by this syntax `$data = array($value);`.

Replace `$data = array($value);`

with

```
$data = array(); 
$data[] = $value;
```

This will append each new `value` to the `&data array`.

[Example](https://3v4l.org/WLTM3)

Also, you have one textarea, it means that the value(text input) of it comes into `name=urls[]` as a first value of array `urls[]`. In PHP you'll get one value.

If you want to separate inputted data you need to split it. For example, if you will write inputs comma separated, then you'll need to make `explode(",",$_POST["urls"];)` at least. By the way, change `name="urls[]"` to simply `name="urls"`.

Use this code for retrieving inputs comma separated:

```
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="urls" cols="150" rows="15" value=""></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Get URLs" />
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['urls']) && !empty($_POST['urls'])) {
  // fetch data from specified url

    $inputs = explode(",",$_POST["urls"]);
    $data = array(); 
    foreach($inputs as $key => $value){ 
        $data[] = $value;
    }
    $r = multiRequest($data);
}
```

As I understood your `multiRequest()` function should process your `$data` array, put this line outside the `foreach` loop. If you won't you will process `$data` array each loop.

**Note:** inputs should be comma separated in this case(in textarea).

Answer (score 0):

If you delimit your urls by a line return, we can split and process them:

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="urls" cols="150" rows="15" value=""></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
```

Omit the square brackets on the input name if we have one textarea.  (Alternatively use many text inputs with the name attribute `urls[]`, to get your input into an array.)

```
<?php
$urls = $_POST['urls'] ?? '';
$urls = preg_split('@\R@', $urls);
$emails = [];
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $pattern = '/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i';
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $url, $matches))
    {
        foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
            $emails[] = $email;
        }
    }
}

if(empty($emails)) {
    echo 'No emails found.';
} else {
    print implode('<br>', $emails);
}
```

The input:

```
http://example.com
mailto://foo@example.com
```

Will output:

```
foo@example.com
```